# If BufReader takes ownership of a stream, how can I read and write lines on it?

Tags: rust, tcp

I want to read a line from a `TCPStream`, write another line to it, and then repeat. The issue is that `BufReader::new` takes ownership of my `TCPStream` variable:

```
let stream = ...; // TCPStream

let reader = BufReader::new(stream); // moved its value

// can't use stream here anymore
```

What is a simple solution to this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114619/access-to-components-of-a-read-wrapped-by-take-or-chain or http://stackoverflow.com/a/31503269/155423.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Solution: use references.

```
let mut stream = ...;
let reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
let writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);
```

---

#### Explanation

If we take a closer look at `BufReader::new`, we see that it takes an argument `inner` of type `R`, where `R` is just any type that implements `Read`:

```
impl<R: Read> BufReader<R> {
    pub fn new(inner: R) -> BufReader<R> { ... }
}
```

We then take a look at `Read` and see this implementation:

```
impl<'a> Read for &'a TcpStream
```

So we can just pass a reference to the `new` function, like so:

```
let reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
```

We will do the same for `BufWriter` and `Write` and will see that indeed there is this implementation:

```
impl<'a> Write for &'a TcpStream
```

So we can, again, use an immutable reference to create the `BufWriter`.

Comment: For crates that don't implement Read and Write for references, such as [serialport](https://gitlab.com/susurrus/serialport-rs), you can use [bufstream](https://github.com/alexcrichton/bufstream)

Answer (score 6):

You have several possibilities:

- do not use a `BufReader`
- temporarily borrow the stream from the `BufReader` using [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.get_mut)
- discard the `BufReader` entirely and recover the stream using [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.into_inner)

I would personally advise not using a `BufReader` unless you really need to bufferize the input; for a single line it does not seem worth it.

Otherwise, if you are done with the buffering, you can recover the underlying stream and if you are not you can temporarily buffer it.

**Caution**: *Do be aware that the `BufReader` bufferizes reads, so when you borrow/recover the inner stream you short-circuit the buffered data; for reading it's an issue, in your case (writing) it should be fine.*