# Why can I just pass an immutable reference to BufReader, instead of a mutable reference?

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, borrowing

I am writing a simple TCP-based echo server. When I tried to use `BufReader` and `BufWriter` to read from and write to a `TcpStream`, I found that passing a `TcpStream` to `BufReader::new()` by value moves its ownership so that I couldn't pass it to a `BufWriter`. Then, I found an answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869078/if-bufreader-takes-ownership-of-a-stream-how-can-i-read-and-write-lines-on-it/35869336) that solves the problem:

```
fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    // Receive a message
    let mut message = String::new();
    reader.read_line(&mut message).unwrap();

    // ingored
}
```

This is simple and it works. However, I can not quite understand why this code works. Why can I just pass an immutable reference to `BufReader::new()`, instead of a mutable reference ?

The whole program can be found [here](https://github.com/SLMT/rust-examples/blob/c95ddba4d71795e22c47c4140dcf900a2440c412/tcp-server/src/main.rs).

**More Details**

In the above code, I used `reader.read_line(&mut message)`. So I opened the source code of `BufRead` in Rust standard library and saw this:

```
fn read_line(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize> {
    // ignored
    append_to_string(buf, |b| read_until(self, b'\n', b))
}
```

Here we can see that it passes the self (which may be a `&mut BufReader` in my case) to `read_until()`. Next, I found the following code in the same file:

```
fn read_until<R: BufRead + ?Sized>(r: &mut R, delim: u8, buf: &mut Vec<u8>)
                                   -> Result<usize> {
    let mut read = 0;
    loop {
        let (done, used) = {
            let available = match r.fill_buf() {
                Ok(n) => n,
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
                Err(e) => return Err(e)
            };
            match memchr::memchr(delim, available) {
                Some(i) => {
                    buf.extend_from_slice(&available[..i + 1]);
                    (true, i + 1)
                }
                None => {
                    buf.extend_from_slice(available);
                    (false, available.len())
                }
            }
        };
        r.consume(used);
        read += used;
        if done || used == 0 {
            return Ok(read);
        }
    }
}
```

In this part, there are two places using the `BufReader`: `r.fill_buf()` and `r.consume(used)`. I thought `r.fill_buf()` is what I want to see. Therefore, I went to the code of `BufReader` in Rust standard library and found this:

```
fn fill_buf(&mut self) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
    // ignored
    if self.pos == self.cap {
        self.cap = try!(self.inner.read(&mut self.buf));
        self.pos = 0;
    }
    Ok(&self.buf[self.pos..self.cap])
}
```

It seems like it uses `self.inner.read(&mut self.buf)` to read the data from `self.inner`. Then, we take a look at the structure of `BufReader` and the `BufReader::new()`:

```
pub struct BufReader<R> {
    inner: R,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    pos: usize,
    cap: usize,
}

// ignored
impl<R: Read> BufReader<R> {
    // ignored
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub fn new(inner: R) -> BufReader<R> {
        BufReader::with_capacity(DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, inner)
    }

    // ignored
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub fn with_capacity(cap: usize, inner: R) -> BufReader<R> {
        BufReader {
            inner: inner,
            buf: vec![0; cap],
            pos: 0,
            cap: 0,
        }
    }

    // ignored
}
```

From the above code, we can know that `inner` is a type which implements `Read`. In my case, the `inner` may be a `&TcpStream`.

I knew the signature of `Read.read()` is:

```
fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>
```

It requires a **mutable** reference here, but I only lent it an **immutable** reference. Is this supposed to be a problem when the program reaches `self.inner.read()` in `fill_buf()` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31503488/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I originally thought TcpStream works in the different way from File. But after reading Lukas Kalbertodt's answer, I suddenly realized the idea behind it is the same. Thank you for your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick anser**: we pass a `&TcpStream` as `R: Read`, not `TcpStream`. Thus `self` in `Read::read` is `&mut & TcpStream`, not `&mut TcpStream`. `Read` is implement for `&TcpStream` as you can see [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html).

Look at this working code:

```
let stream = TcpStream::connect("...").unwrap();
let mut buf = [0; 100];
Read::read(&mut (&stream), &mut buf);
```

Note that `stream` is not even bound as `mut`, because we use it immutably, just having a mutable reference to the immutable one.

---

**Next**, you could ask why `Read` can be implemented for `&TcpStream`, because it's necessary to mutate *something* during the read operation.

This is where the nice Rust-world  ☮ ends, and the evil C-/operating system-world starts . For example, on Linux you have a simple integer as "file descriptor" for the stream. You can use this for all operations on the stream, including reading and writing. Since you pass the integer by value (it's also a `Copy`-type), it doesn't matter if you have a mutable or immutable reference to the integer as you can just copy it.

Therefore a minimal amount of synchronization has to be done by the operating system or by the Rust `std` implementation, because usually it's strange and dangerous to mutate through an immutable reference. This behavior is called "interior mutability" and you can read a little bit more about it...

- in [the `cell` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html)
- in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/mutability.html#interior-vs-exterior-mutability)

Comment: I totally didn't expect `self` is a `&mut & TcpStream`!! But, what exactly is it ? I mean... what is a mutable reference to a reference ? If I called `self.something`, would that have the same effect when `self` was a `TcpStream` or a `&TcpStream` ?

Comment: @YushanLin *would that have the same effect* -> in this case yes. The dot-syntax does a few things, like deref-coercions. This topic is too big for a follow up comment ^_^

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. Your supplement about why `Read` can be implemeneted for an immutable reference is useful !! Your answer helps me a lot.