# How do I give a TcpStream to a BufReader but then take it back?

Tags: memory-management, reference, rust, borrowing

I have a struct:

```
pub struct Paradise {
    cstream: TcpStream,
}
```

with a method:

```
pub fn write_message(&mut self, code: i32, message: &str) {
    let foo = format!("{} {}\r\n", code, message);
    let _ = self.cstream.write(foo.as_bytes());
}
```

That works great. It's an FTP server so when I get a new `TcpStream` from `TcpListener::bind` I do:

```
let mut p = Paradise::new(stream);
p.start();
```

And inside that `start` method I call:

```
self.write_message(220, "Welcome to Paradise");
```

and sure enough, I see that message in the FTP client. So far so good.

But then I do:

```
let mut br = BufReader::new(&self.cstream);
loop {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let _ = br.read_line(&mut buffer);
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
    self.write_message(550, "Testing");
}
```

And when I get to the next `write_message` call inside the loop:

> cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.cstream` is also
>   borrowed as immutable [E0502]

Full code:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/tinted_paradise/blob/169cc5f7025c417814f47a1fb3e3fc78ce4f9516/src/paradise.rs

https://github.com/andrewarrow/tinted_paradise/blob/169cc5f7025c417814f47a1fb3e3fc78ce4f9516/src/starter.rs

How can I change stuff around so I *can* call `write_message` inside the loop?

Comment: There are currently [72 questions for the error message you've specified](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq+borrow+as+mutable+because+is+also+borrowed+as+immutable+).

Comment: ^ are you saying I'm using stack overflow incorrectly to learn rust? Why are you so against learning?

Comment: Haha, I'm certainly not against *learning*. I *am* (obliquely) pointing out that multiple people have spent significant time explaining that error message to ~70 people in ~70 contexts. It would be courteous to read (a good portion of) them in addition to the [normal Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) and explain what makes your question different. Note that I answered the question you asked in the title, which seemed unique, but perhaps is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35869078/155423 or those linked from there.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that "Why are you so against learning?" is some kind of logical fallacy or similar... ^_^

Comment: @AndrewArrow: The purpose of stackoverflow is to get an answer to your question *without* having to ask it. It also aims at *consolidating* knowledge, rather than having it scattered across a dozen half-hearted explanations among so many pages. This means that, in general, if you ask a question that has already been asked, it should be closed. If the answers on the already asked question are insufficient, then it is best to improve *those* rather than leave incomplete answers there. As a corollary, a different question need to clearly indicate *how* it is different; it may not be obvious.

Comment: I dunno guys, I think my question was pretty intelligently worded and showed I was really trying. I read the other 72 questions but wanted to ask it my way. What if a college professor responded to an intelligent question from a student with RTFM? Also @Shepmaster what is wrong with using tags in github? https://github.com/andrewarrow/tinted_paradise/tree/so2 so2 is a tag just for this question.

Comment: My rationale for tags -> hashes is in [the edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39067812/revisions). *I read the other 72 questions* — that is very impressive, kudos! I hope you remembered to upvote Q&A you found useful while reading. It also means that you should be extremely capable of explaining the difference between those questions and this one, making it possible to give a useful answer here. **Now that you've read all the existing answers**, us restating existing answers cannot possibly help you, so helping us understand the difference is the only way you can get a useful answer

Comment: I believe a professor would start by asking "What have you tried?" I agree your question is well-worded and readable, but *as it is currently written*, it doesn't show any effort to fix the problem. Right now, it's awfully close to "here is my code, here is an error, people on SO will fix it for me".

Answer (score 4):

> How do I give a TcpStream to a BufReader but then take it back?

By calling [`BufReader::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.into_inner):

> ```
> impl<R: Read> BufReader<R> {
>     fn into_inner(self) -> R
> }
> ```
>
> Unwraps this `BufReader`, returning the underlying reader.
>
> Note that any leftover data in the internal buffer is lost.